# magento 2 configurable products has not shipping methods in checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

In my Magento 2 (2.1.11) configurable products has not shipping methods in checkout.

Configurable and virtual products has weight

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a configurable product with child products which are 'automatically' generated. These child items will have no weight. As a result, they are virtual products and virtual products don't have shipping method because we don't need to ship virtual product. there are no delivery methods in virtual products.

By changing type_id in the catalog_product_entity table you can resolve this issue.

**You can convert all virtual products to the simple product by just one query.**

```
update catalog_product_entity set type_id = 'simple' where type_id = 'virtual';
```

**But beware, this query converts all virtual products to simple. (better to create DB backup before the start)**